# How do you find out what parts of code are creating the most virtual memory?

Tags: c++, linux, memory, malloc

I have a program that starts up and within about 5 minutes the virtual size of process is about 13 gigs.  It runs on Linux, uses boost, gnu c++ library and various other 3rd party libraries.

After 5 minutes size stays at 13 gigs and rss size steady at around 5 gigs.

I can't just run it in a debugger because at startup about 30 threads are started, each of which starts running its own code, that does various allocations. So stepping through and checking virtual memory at different parts of code at each breakpoint is not feasible.

I thought of changing program to start each thread one at a time to make it easier to track allocation of memory,  but before doing this are there any good tools?

Valgrind is fairly slow,  maybe tcmalloc could provide the info?

Comment: what kind of program is it? What is it size? Can you show some of the source code?

Comment: What are the 3rd party libraries? Describe much more what kind of program are you working on!

Comment: Much of memory is read from database tables, and read into std sets.  It also is receiving data from sockets across the network. We are talking millions of db rows but 13g excessive IMHO.

Comment: I hv other programs that use same libraries that don't read the rows and better with memory so we think db reading into sets is issue

Answer (score 0):

I would use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) (perhaps run it an entire night) or else use [Boehm GC](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/).

Alternatively, use the [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) filesystem to understand (e.g. thru `/proc/$pid/statm` & `/proc/$pid/maps`) when a lot of memory gets allocated.

The most important is to find [memory leaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). If the memory don't grow after startup it is less an issue.

Perhaps adding instance counters to each class might help (use atomic integers or mutexes to serialize them).

If the program's source code is big (e.g. a million of source lines) so that spending several days/weeks is worth the effort, perhaps customizing the GCC compiler (e.g. with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)) might be relevant.

---

#### a `std::set` minibenchmark

You mentioned big `std::set` based upon million rows.

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

class MyElem
{
  int _n;
  char _s[16-sizeof(_n)];
public:
  MyElem(int k) :  _n(k)
  {
    snprintf (_s, sizeof(_s), "%d", k);
  };
  ~MyElem()
  {
    _n=0;
    memset(_s, 0, sizeof(_s));
  };
  int n() const
  {
    return _n;
  };
  std::string str() const
  {
    return std::string(_s);
  };
  bool less(const MyElem&x) const
  {
    return _n < x._n;
  };
};

bool operator < (const MyElem& l, const MyElem& r)
{
  return l.less(r);
}

typedef std::set<MyElem> MySet;

void bench (int cnt, MySet& set)
{
  for (long i=0; i<(long)cnt*1024; i++)
    set.insert(MyElem(i));
  time_t now = 0;
  time (&now);
  set.insert (((now) & 0xfffffff) * 100);
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  MySet s;
  clock_t cstart, cend;
  int c = argc>1?atoi(argv[1]):256;
  if (c<16) c=16;
  printf ("c=%d Kiter\n", c);
  cstart = clock();
  bench (c, s);
  cend = clock();
  int x = getpid();
  char cmdbuf[64];
  snprintf(cmdbuf, sizeof(cmdbuf), "pmap %d", x);
  printf ("running %s\n", cmdbuf);
  fflush (NULL);
  system(cmdbuf);
  putchar('\n');
  printf ("at end c=%d Kiter clockdiff=%.2f millisec = %.f µs/Kiter\n",
          c, (cend-cstart)*1.0e-3, (double)(cend-cstart)/c);
  if (s.find(x) != s.end())
    printf("set has %d\n", x);
  else
    printf("set don't contain %d\n", x);
  return 0;
}
```

Notice the 16 bytes `sizeof(MyElem)`. On Debian/Sid/AMD64 with GCC 4.8.1 (intel i3770K processor, 16Gbytes RAM) and compiling that bench with  `g++ -Wall -O1 tset.cc -o ./tset-01`

With 32768 thousands of iterations, so 32M elements:

> total          2109592K

(last line above given by `pmap`)

> at end c=32768 Kiter clockdiff=16470.00 millisec = 503 µs/Kiter

Then the implicit `time` from my `zsh`

> ./tset-01 32768  16.77s user 0.54s system 99% cpu 17.343 total

This is about 2.1Gbytes. so perhaps 64.3 bytes per element & `set` member overhead (since `sizeof(MyElem)==16` the set seems to have a non-negligible cost of perhaps 6 words per element)

Comment: I'll give the valgrind a try and let it run.  I think you are correct that std overhead is not much.  My guess is perhaps all the threads starting at once and doing allocations is fragmenting the memory.  In past I hv had big success using a string pool for this data since the columns in the table often contain same strings many times.  Think about employee database, if a string is used for the employee's department field often sharing the string saves memory. Use ref counting strings.